# Dynamic title attribute in knockoutjs

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I want to set title attribute of span dynamically. I have tried below:

```
<span id="aPublic" class="pointer" 
 data-bind="attr:{title: {'mark private': isPublic, 'mark public': !isPublic()}}">
</span>
```

But it gives me [object Object].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot do this in such way. Create `computed` value in your view model that will return needed `title` depends on `isPublic` property:

```
self.title = ko.computed(function(){
   return self.isPublic() ? 'mark private' : 'mark public';
});
```

Or you can do this inside `data-bind` attribute but it is not considered the best of solutions:

```
<span id="aPublic" class="pointer" 
 data-bind="attr:{title: isPublic() ? 'mark private': 'mark public'}">
</span>
```